# Maximum Likelihood through a noisy channel

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, multinomial-distribution

I have a random variable $X$, which can take $n$ values and is distributed according to multinomial $\Theta=(\theta_1, \theta_2, \cdots, \theta_n)$. I observe a random variable $Y$, where I have that $P(Y=j|X=i)=c_{j,i}$.

Let $C$ be the matrix $[C_{j,i}]_{1\leq j,i \leq n}$. I have that $C$ is a full rank matrix.

There are $m$ iid draws of $(X,Y)$. I only observe the values of $Y$ there. I want to get an ML estimate of $\Theta$.

Let $\Psi=(\psi_1,\cdots, \psi_n)$, where $\hat{\psi}_i=P(Y=i)$. The ML estimate of  $\Psi$ is clearly the vector of empirical frequencies. Let us call this $\hat{\Psi}$.

I wanted to know if the ML estimate of $\Theta$, $\hat{\Theta}= C^{-1}\hat{\Psi}$. I can prove it if $n=2$, but do not seem to be able to show this for a general $n$.